# Neural network model fails to predict outer world data

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, neural-network, classification, prediction

I built a neural network to predict a certain kind of data ( biological sequences ). It has 32 features where 12 have certain units and 20 are simply integers ( but positive). My positive set has 648 samples and negatives 9000+ samples.

To train my network I took 500 samples of both and rest were used for testing. When I trained and tested my network with 3 folds cross-validation it gave 100 % accuracy for all cases, provided I normalised the input data before partitioning them into training and testing sets.  Precision and Recall is 100%

When I don't normalise it the accuracy falls to 65-70 % for the same experiment. Precision and recall is 5% and 80% respectively.

The case has become more peculiar. When I use the network trained in first ( normalised one) model to test on several random datasets which were present in the training sets, without normalising ( as outer world data can not be normalised because we deal with single instances) it predicts all samples as 1 or positives, completely biased to positives.

When I use the second model ( the unnormalised one) it predicts more false negatives.

If 'outp' is the output prediction of training set positives and 'outn' is the output prediction of training set negatives, I calculated threshold for my network as :

```
[ mean(outp) - std_dev(outp) + mean( outn) + std_dev(outn)] / 2
```

I got 0.5 for the first model and for second model is 0.489

1) Where is the problem ? Can someone explain me that.

2) When we train, it is recommended to normalise the data but doesn't it mean that the classifier will mis-interprete the input values if provided by a user who is going to use the prediction tool, because a single sample can not be normalised ?

3) Also what is the best method to find threshold in such problems or say classifier problems in general ?

4) What else information I should provide I don't know. Please let me know that too.

I am providing link to the epoch to error plots.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/1gideuvbeje2lip/model2_unnormalised.jpg
https://www.dropbox.com/s/nb4zyt3h370pk8m/model1_normalised.jpg

One more thing I would like to mention, to normalize I used the MATLAB's built in function

My positive matrix is 32 features by 648 samples ( i.e 32 x 648 )

and negative matrix is 32 features by 9014 samples ( i.e 32 x 9014 )

both were normalized using initially before any partitioning as train or test or validate sets by `normr` function of MATLAB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can normalize your data, but then when you receive new input from a user, you must normalize their data by using the same 'min' and 'max' you used when you trained your network.
As the built-in function don't give you those values, you may want to normalize the matrix by hand and then store 'min' and max' to later normalize user input.

I use this formula but others exist:

```
MatNorm = (Mat - min(Mat)) / (max(Mat) - min(Mat))
```

Also, how many positive test data did you use training?

Comment: so this formula has to be used column wise that is for matrix of 
32 features x 648 samples , the normalisation will be for all the features of a sample. Am I right ? because then only it is possible to  keep the same normalisation for a single user input.

Comment: You can keep several 'max' and 'min', one for each feature of your input.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the [standard scaling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalization_%28statistics%29) strategy, apply the same `mean` and `std` value that obtained from training to your validation/test data for the normalization. A 10-fold cross validation is also recommended.